# Polymer form not ajax-ing in firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, polymer, polymer-1.0

Here is my form:

```
    <form is="iron-form" action="{{url('/user/store')}}" id="registerForm" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <paper-input name="email" label="E-mail" type="email"></paper-input>
        <paper-input name="password" label="password" type="password"></paper-input>
        <paper-button raised onclick="submitLRForm(event);">Submit form</paper-button>
    </form>
```

In google chrome it sends the form data trough ajax, but in firefox it does it the normal way (redirects to `/user/store`)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
G3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Firefox 44 under Linux and swapping `webcomponents-lite` for `webcomponents` solved it, i.e.:

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**:

for reference and according to the [docs](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/), the lite version includes

> support for just Custom Elements and HTML Imports. This is useful if
>   you don't require Shadow DOM in your application.

Shadow DOM is not supported by default (see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom)) as of FireFox 44, but it can be enabled under `about:config` with key `dom.webcomponents.enabled`.

Comment: Hmm, with `dom.webcomponents.enabled` set to true, the Polymer page doesn't even load (just an empty page with two 304 status events in the log for webcomponents.js and my custom .js file. It still works in Vivaldi/Chrome. With it set to false, the page works in Firefox too, but still not the Ajax form (nothing happens, no events or requests).